# Proving a limit of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the limit as $z$ approaches $i$ of the following expression:

$$\frac{z^2+i}{z^4-1}$$

I tried doing manipulations like we learn in calculus 1 but I can't get a zero to leave the denominator!

Comment: The limit does not exist: The top approaches the non-zero number $-1+i$.

Comment: @Matthew Perhaps in the denominator that $i$ could be a $1$ ??

Comment: Are you sure? 2 sources say the limit is -1/2

Comment: http://gyazo.com/34ddd2e6c64fa6a635571929476b087d.png

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2+i}{z^4-1}$$

and let $u=z-i$ hence
$$f(z)=f(u+i)=\frac{u^2+2iu+i-1}{u^4+4iu^3-6u^2-4iu}=\frac1u\frac{u^2+2iu+i-1}{u^3+4iu^2-6u-4i}$$
so 
$$|f(z)|^2=\frac1{u^2}\frac{(u^2-1)^2+(2u+1)^2}{(u^3-6u)^2+(4u^2-4)^2}\to \infty\;\text{when}\;u\to0$$
hence 
$$\lim_{z\to i}f(z)\;\text{is undefined}$$

Comment: Are you sure? 2 sources say the limit is -1/2

Comment: I'm afraid that you have a typo in your question, check it!

Comment: http://gyazo.com/34ddd2e6c64fa6a635571929476b087d.png

Comment: @Matthew I think that the typo is in your book, in fact if 
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{z^4-1}$$
then in this case 
$$\lim_{z\to i}f(z)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{z^2+1}{(z^2-1)(z^2+1)}=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{1}{(z^2-1)}=-\frac12$$